# Tip for worst case of quicksort implementation

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to implement quick sort and figuring out the handling part for worst case of it. When pivot choose largest or lowest of element in the array, I got stuck in the middle of my algorithm and have no idea how to handle it.

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int item1, int item2)
{
    int temp = item1;
    item1 = item2;
    item2 = temp;
}

int partition(int array[], unsigned int left, unsigned int right)
{
    int pivot = array[left];
    int pivot_index = left;

    for(++left, right; left <= right;)
    {
        if(array[left] >= pivot && array[right] < pivot)
            swap(array[left], array[right]);

        if(array[left] < pivot)
            left++;
        if(array[right] >= pivot)
            right++;
    }

    swap(array[right], pivot_index); 

    return right;
}

void quicksort(int array[], unsigned int left, unsigned int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int index = partition(array, left, right);
        quicksort(array, 0, index - 1);
        quicksort(array, index + 1, right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int unsortedarray[] = {10, 0, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8, 1};
    int length = sizeof(unsortedarray) / sizeof(int);

    quicksort(unsortedarray, 0, length - 1);

    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < static_cast<unsigned int>(length); ++index)
        std::cout << unsortedarray[index] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lookup "median of 3"

Comment: Worst case for a sort is is *never* "stuck". If the algorithm hangs then there is a logical error - likely an off-by-one - and has nothing to do with "complexity" per se.

Comment: Please include more details. Exactly where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just want to know how to handle without well-known way to choose pivot or intro-sort.

Comment: @Nooo0b Median-of-3 Pivot and Random Pivot are two methods used to handle mitigating the worst-case *complexity*. Using such won't magically "fix" a broken implementation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap` is working with local copies of the values to be swapped; it isn't making any changes to the arguments.

Comment: Thanks. So swap func() should be like swap(int* arg1, int* arg2) ?

Comment: And you'll need to change the calls accordingly.  Or you can make the parameters call-by-reference.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I just modified my code to do swap the values without swap function, add temp = array[right];    array[right] = array[pivot_index];    array[pivot_index] = temp; But still cannot understand how does it works when pivot is largest or smallest element. What can I do if left or right variable cannot find any element fit on it?

Comment: If pivot is the smallest element, then there will be no swapping (since `array[right]<pivot` will never be true), and `right` will keep getting incremented (oops!).

Comment: YES! That's what I thought and want to know how to handle in that case. Even I change to 'array[right] < pivot &&  left <= right', it just helps to right can't be less than left which is not a solution for this case.